# avoiding recreation of a page when navigating between pages in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows, xaml, mvvm

This is a question regarding navigation between pages in Windows 8 app -

How can I avoid the re-creation of the page when navigating between pages ?

For example - Whether I'm using frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage1), null); or Frame.GoBack(); (after switching to another page from MyPage1), a new instance of MyPage1 will be created.
I want to avoid it in order to keep the same UI state in MyPage1. Using MVVM, I can restore most of it, but not all... (for instance, selected item in a tree). How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the constructor of the page that you do not want destroyed:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```